# Android: Expandable ListView - Update view visibility in child

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I've a Expandable ListView and want to update view (ImageView or ToggleButton) visibility placed inside the children on click of button placed in parent group.
I'm successfully able to update content of other views inside the children but can't get visibility worked. After struggling for hours I've come here.

Here is my getChildView method in Adapter class which indeed extends BaseExpandableListAdapter

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

    final NavDrawerItem children = (NavDrawerItem) getChild(groupPosition,
            childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        viewHolder.txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        viewHolder.circleIcon = (CircleView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        viewHolder.btnDelete = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_delete);
        if (children.isDeleteBtnVisible())
            viewHolder.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            viewHolder.btnDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //viewHolder.headerImgIcon = (ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.iconHeader);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();

    }
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setText(children.getTitle());
    // Set custom font
    Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(),TypeFaceUtility.getNavDrawerFont()); 
    viewHolder.txtTitle.setTypeface(type);

    viewHolder.circleIcon.circleFillColor = children.getIconColor();

    if (children.getCount() > 0){
        viewHolder.txtCount.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.txtCount.setText("" + children.getCount());
    }else
        viewHolder.txtCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    return convertView;
}
```

GetGroupView Method

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderHeader viewHolder;
    final NavGroup group = (NavGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
    final NavDrawerItem groupItem = group.navDrawerItem;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_header, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolderHeader();
        viewHolder.headerImgIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iconHeader);
        viewHolder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.title);

        viewHolder.txtCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.counter);
        viewHolder.iconExpand = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.icon_expand);
        viewHolder.iconCollapse = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.icon_collapse);
        viewHolder.btnNavSetting = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_nav_setting);
        viewHolder.btnNavSetting.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("NavAdapter",groupItem.getTitle());
                enableDelete(groupPosition, true);

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderHeader) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

enableDelete method which is being called from Group view

```
   private void enableDelete(int groupPosition, boolean enabled) {
    NavGroup group = (NavGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
    for (int i = 0; i < group.children.size(); i++) {
            group.children.get(i).setDeleteBtnVisible(enabled);

    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Layout XML for child

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="@drawable/nav_drawer_listitem_textcolor_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
 <ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_nav_delete"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/title"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_action_delete"
    android:textOff=""
    android:textOn="" 
    android:visibility="visible"/> 

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/counter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@drawable/nav_drawer_listitem_textcolor_selector" />
```

What I want to do when user touch the btn_nav_setting in the group, I want to make btn_nav_delete visible in the Children and hide the btn_nav_delete when Group is collapsed.
Any help would be highly appreciated.